# Can't access internet from inside Virtual Box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have used Virtual Box on my system before and was able to access the internet. I just reinstalled Virtual Box and installed XP inside it. I cannot access the internet from within.

When I look in the device manager under network adapters, it is showing "VMWare Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter." It says the device cannot start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I right-clicked on the network card in the device manager and two cards showed up. I selected the other card and it worked.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Don't forget to mark your own post as the accepted answer!

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case I changed the adapter type to "Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net)". Also I'm using this with Ubuntu. But the problem did seem to be resolved by changing the "Adapter Type".

Comment: @Phenom, What do you mean by "card"? Do you mean "Settings >> Network >> Adapter"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebooted your physical machine?  Sometimes after a reinstall of VBox, the OS needs to restart the appropriate drivers and/or virtual devices (in this case, I think VBox uses a virtual networking card which needs to be restarted).

Comment: Rebooting didn't change anything.

Comment: Ditto for me, rebooted lots of times but didn't change anything.