# VirtualBox's Internet doesn't work no matter what

Tags: macos, networking, internet, virtualbox, virtual-machine

None of my VirtualBox virtual machine can use the internet. I've tried every possible configuration of networking ad it never works. Occasionally, just out of the blue, without changing anything, the internet starts working, but stops just as suddenly after a little while. It starts or stops working while I'm using a VM. How can I use the internet from a VM?
I am running MacOS 10.5.7 on a MacBook. **Edit**: I mean that I'm running MacOS 10.5.7 as the Host OS. **Edit 2**: Whenever I try to use the internet the network icon on the bottom of the window has a little red circle blink.

Comment: Does the answer at [Can't access internet from inside Virtual Box](http://superuser.com/questions/164548/cant-access-internet-from-inside-virtual-box) apply?

Comment: Nope. I've tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had any problem accessing the internet with the default (NAT) networking configuration and used bridged mode with no trouble also. I run a Win-XP-32 host with Linux guests.

NAT mode is by far the easiest to set up as the defaults work out of the box.  **If you are having trouble with NAT mode then you likely have a bad install of VirtualBox.**

Bridged mode is convenient if you want to access shared resources on your home network or use the guest OS as some sort of server.  However, it is unlikely your ISP allows multiple IP addresses to face the cable/DSL modem.  So, in order to use bridged mode you will probably need a router (with NAT enabled) between your ISP and the rest of your network (even if it's just the one physical machine.)

Comment: Agreed that it may be a bad install. Try reinstalling virtual box - it's possible the network drivers it adds got misconfigured or removed or otherwise messed up.

Comment: I've never used the OS-X version of VirtualBox.  I know the Windows version pops up all kinds of warnings about non-certified drivers when installing.  All are safe to ignore.

Comment: I reinstalled VirtualBox (from the same disk image) and it still does not work. I haven't tried updating it and will see if that works though.

Comment: I clicked "Check for updates" in the VirtualBox menu and it says: "Unable to obtain the new version information due to the following error: **HTTP request failed** ", but my host internet is working fine. Does this have something to do with VirtualBox's network drivers?

Comment: Sounds like you have networking issues in general.  It could be VBox's network drivers are not installed/configured correctly.  Sorry, but I have no experience with it on Mac so can't help there.

Answer (score 1):

When I went on Windows 7 to `Network And Internet --> Network Connections` , it seemed to work great after I clicked `Diagnose`. I'm using NAT on a pretty old install of VirtualBox without a problem. Try doing this and see if it works, something about "DHCP" being disabled was corrected after I did this.

You can see a screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: worked for me. I diagnosed the ethernet connection called "VirtualBox host only ethernet..."